# How to safely send a user data in API call

Tags: python, flask-restful

Created a Flash Restful API with various end points for my website. Some endpoints need the users username and password to get user specific data. I’m currently sending these as parameters in the API call but I’m assuming this isn’t secure so how does one do this safely?

Comment: You need to look at authentication and authorization

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of differing ways to do this but it's generally accepted that using tokens, which can be revoked, are a more secure way of doing auth than using a username/password combo.  This is due to the inability to retract a username/password if they got leaked.

I'd suggest reading the following blog by Miguel.  He explains password authentication followed by tokens.

[Miguel Grinberg](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/restful-authentication-with-flask)

Answer (score 0):

you can make a seperate api route that acts as a login and returns a sessionID/token on a successful login that can be used for authenticating to those endpoints you mentioned.